# Websockets : onmessage is not firing.!

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, ratchet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hi</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="conn"> This : </div>
<input type="text" id="text">
<input type="button" value="Button" onclick="func()" id="btn">

<script>
    var fees=document.getElementById("conn");
    var btn=document.getElementById("btn");
    var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

    function func()
    {
        var text=document.getElementById("text").value;
        conn.send(text);
        conn.send('any msg');
        text.innerHTML+= text+'<br/>';
    }

    conn.onopen = function(e) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
    };

    conn.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
        fees.innerHTML+= e.data+'<br/>';
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This my code for running websocket. i am using ratchet websockets and xampp server.
Main problem is the onmessage is not firing ! (I don't know why).

Console shows that connection established!.
No more errors on console.
Please help ... thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you sent a message to the browser?

Comment: How to send it ? . Sorry but i can't understand !

Comment: `onmessage` is waiting for a message to be sent to the web browser from the pother side of the socket. It will not 'fire' until it receives a message. Make sure you go through all of the [examples in Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/push).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have successfully implemented [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) websockets.

I think it is easier to implement that Ratchet websocket